# Possible technique to send video from ffmpeg to html5 video

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am searching for a technique to stream a video to a html5 player and came across ffmpeg. It seems to be able to do that but the quality it has is extradorinary bad (I only tried streaming on a rtp stream).
I got ffmpeg to stream a rtp stream which cannot be played in the html5 player or vlc player, only ffplay.

Is there some way to increase the quality up to a level where Full HD at 60fps is supported? This is all about local netowrk so traffic and performance should not be a problem.

Are there any (maybe better) techniques to realize a real-time streaming?
Is it furthermore possible to pause ffmpeg while it is streaming a movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebM is the way to go for "HTML5" video streaming.

I've written a bit about avconv/ffmpeg streaming of WebM here: https://plus.google.com/+ThomasRuecker/posts/1RCeYxHhiY3

As you want 1080p60 you will have to trade quality for real time encoding (unless you preencode your content). I don't remember the necessary parameters for avconv, so you'll have to consult its manual. Also playing around with multi-threading options might be helpful. Regardless a high CPU core frequency for the machine running the encoder is paramount.

Comment: The provided link is dead.